# Android: How to make the views the same height dynamically

Tags: android, android-layout, view

I'm making one table in Android application. 
Now I cannot make the views the same height.

- There are 2 `TextView`s, `tmp_name` and `tmp_content` in each row.
- the height of `tmp_content` depends on the length of `course_description(i)`.
- `tmp_content` sets its height automatically.

I'd like to get the height of `tmp_content` and reset the height of `tmp_name` same with `tmp_content`.

If you have any tips, please let me know.

```
for (int i = 0; i < course_name.size(); i++) {
    TableRow.LayoutParams lp = new TableRow.LayoutParams(TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, TableRow.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT);
    lp.setMargins(1, 1, 1, 1);

    TextView tmp_name = new TextView(General.this);
    tmp_name.setText(course_name.get(i));
    tmp_name.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    tmp_name.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tmp_name.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));

    TextView tmp_content = new TextView(General.this);
    tmp_content.setHorizontallyScrolling(false);
    tmp_content.setPadding(10, 0, 10, 0);
    tmp_content.setLayoutParams(lp);
    tmp_content.setBackgroundColor(getResources().getColor(R.color.white));
    tmp_content.setText(course_discription.get(i));

    TableRow tmp_row = new TableRow(General.this);
    tmp_row.addView(tmp_name);
    tmp_row.addView(tmp_content);
    tmp_row.setGravity(Gravity.CENTER_VERTICAL);

    course_display.removeView(tmp_row);
    course_display.addView(tmp_row);

}
```

Comment: This can be done using relativelayout. Set the height of both the views to depend on this layout. Now dynamically set the height of this relative layoút instead of tmp_content. Since both textview's height depends on this layout, they both will get the height dynamically.

Comment: Thank you for your replies! How can I do with using `minHeight` ?