# Android: How to make views the same height dynamically with using minHeight?

Tags: java, android, android-view

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [Android: How to make the views the same height dynamically](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11722646/android-how-to-make-the-views-the-same-height-dynamically)

How to make views the same height dynamically with using `minHeight` ?

I'm making one table in Android application. Now I cannot make the views the same height.

- There are 2 `TextView`s, `tmp_name` and `tmp_content` in each row.
- the height of `tmp_content` depends on the length of `course_description(i)`.
- `tmp_content` sets its height automatically.
- I'd like to get the height of `tmp_content` and reset the height of `tmp_name` same with `tmp_content`.

If you have any tips, please let me know.

Answer (score 0):

You can simply do this,

```
    int height=tmp_content.getHeight();
    tmp_name.setHeight(height);
```

get the height of your TextView after setting the content and then provide the value to your next TextView